# Running method in the background to update UI

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I run a method in the background for c# wpf? It is a packet sniffing method which will update the UI whenever new data is received, do I have to use dispatcher.invoke?

Comment: Update the UI how? Are you just binding some data to various UI elements and that data gets updated? Or something else? The more specific you are, the better the answers people can give.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Dispatcher or the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx): See [Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to do this in WPF, but here's one very simple way using `Task` to do the work on another thread and then dispatching the UI updating back to the main thread:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // some work (packet sniffing)

    // update UI
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        // update my controls here
    }));
});
```